# Get all items on strapi collection

Tags: node.js, strapi

I am using Strapi API on my project, and I would like export my data in CSV file format.

For this, I use a `find()` request, but the API returns only the first 100 items and I've ~ 2000 items in my database.

Is it possible to remove the `limit` on my Strapi request ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For that, you will have to use the `_limit` filter and use `-1` as value.

eg. `strapi.query('restaurant).find({_limit: -1});`

After that I suggest you export directly from your database it will be easier.